# Elasticsearch conflict while putting document to index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl, aws-elasticsearch

I want to create an index and modify its setting with template and at the same time create an alias for it

```
"template_1" : {
    "order" : 0,
    "index_patterns" : [
      "test*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "2",
        "number_of_replicas" : "2"
      }
    },
    "mappings" : { },
    "aliases" : { 
        "some-alias" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

when I am trying to put a document using alias, it tries to create an index with the alias name. However I am looking for something which will search for the index which has this alias and throws an error that there are no index exist with this alias

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are referencing multiple indexes with a single alias, so when you `PUT` a document ES does not know in which document to store it to.
Quoting the doc:

> If no write index is specified and there are multiple indices referenced by an alias, then writes will not be allowed.

One solution, as per quote above, is to specify a *write index* ([see docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/indices-aliases.html#aliases-write-index)) as the default destination for new documents (its also possible to specify [rollover rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/indices-rollover-index.html) to update it).

The other solution, of course, is use the actual index name when putting docs.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Cavaz, I will surely update that. there will be only one index which will have "is_write_index" as true
However my problem here is that, first time there will be no index and no alias then how can I use alias in that case

Comment: Service which will put the records will use 
PUT /some-alias/_doc which will put records to test4 index

`test1 - is_write_index - false,
test2 - is_write_index - false,
test3 - is_write_index - false,
test4 - is_write_index - true`